# Vectorized I/O in WIN32 API

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there an equivalent to POSIX writev()/readv() functions in the WIN32 API? I would like to test our windrbd driver with those functions (if they exist).

Comment: Vectored I/O is also known as Scatter/Gather I/O. Have a look at the Win32 [`ReadFileScatter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365469.aspx) and [`WriteFileGather()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365749.aspx) functions. Note that the POSIX functions are synchronous, whereas the Win32 functions are asynchronous. If you need to be synchronous, you can use [`GetOverlappedResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209.aspx) with `bWait=TRUE`.

Comment: from driver view you anyway got single `IRP_MJ_WRITE` or `IRP_MJ_READ` on this api (Scatter/Gather I/O.) and buffer will be described with already allocated `MDL`. driver simply read or write to this mdl, so technical almost no different compare plain ReadFile/WriteFile request. main different - buffer already described with MDL, when with ReadFile/WriteFile request usually no

Comment: @RbMm, yes, from the driver POV it's just an IRP with a MDL, which the driver maps via `MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe` (i.e. [`MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff554629)). `NtReadFileScatter` and `NtWriteFileGather` replace the single `Buffer` parameter with a `SegmentArray` of buffers that are potentially non-contiguous in virtual memory. Then, in contrast to typical direct I/O on a single buffer, it calls [`MmProbeAndLockSelectedPages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh406526) instead of `MmProbeAndLockPages`.

Comment: To clarify the above comment, the "it" that calls  `MmProbeAndLockSelectedPages` is the I/O manager, not the driver. The driver gets the MDL with resident pages, locked in memory.

Comment: Receving a single request with multiple MDL elements is exactly what I would expect to see. I will implement the feature (with test) this week and it should appear at the public windrbd repository at https://github.com/LINBIT/windrbd beginning of next week.

Comment: Sorry can't read. I finally made the test and got a MDL with one element with mapped memory to the buffer elements. One should note that ReadFileScatter/WriteFileGather requires the memory to be on page boundaries (in addition to the file being opened with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED) which is a restriction which readv/writev don't have. Thanks for your comments. Is there a way to create a test that does an I/O request with multiple MDL elements (I mean from user space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) pointed out in his comment, [ReadFileScatter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365469.aspx) and [WriteFileGather()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365749.aspx) are the functions which closely match (except for
being Asynchronous) the readv/writev POSIX equivalents. Thank you
all for your comments.